# Why is a sampling frequency of 8000 Hz or below more commonly used than above such as 44100 Hz in heart sound analysis?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, frequency

I have a heart sound dataset that contains different sampling frequency. They are 4000 Hz and 44100 Hz. For now, I used 4000 Hz because many journals use the same fs.

My question: Why 4000 Hz or 8000 Hz are commonly used for heart sound analysis more than 44100 Hz?

Comment: Question belongs on https://dsp.stackexchange.com, but essentially the answer is that you are only really interested in relatively low frequency information, so sampling at 44.1 kHz just produces a lot of redundant data that then needs storage/processing.

Answer (score 1):

Sampling at 4000Hz is sufficient to capture all frequencies < 2000Hz.

This is what 2000Hz sounds like (warning, it's loud):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0voTVFmpVjY

As you can hear, 2000Hz has a higher pitch than just about anything you hear in heart sounds, except for some high frequency parts of swishy blood noise.

A 4000Hz sampling rate is therefore sufficient to capture everything of interest in most heart sound analyses.

Note, however, that if you're going to sample at 4000Hz, you MUST filter out everything above 2000Hz first.  Otherwise all the higher frequency noise will be reflected down into the 2000Hz region and will interfere with your signal.